# How to pass parameters to a makefile recipe, or resolve variables at parse time

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I'm dealing with a rather complex makefile system, and I'd like to be able to either pass parameters to a recipe, or have variables in a recipe resolved at parsing time, rather than when executed.  Here's a simplified example of of what's going on.

**Makefile**

```
all : dep_chain

MYVAR := hello
include depchain.mk

MYVAR := world
include depchain.mk

dep_chain : $(DEPCHAIN)
```

**depchain.mk**

```
$(MYVAR) : $(DEPCHAIN)
    @echo $(MYVAR)

DEPCHAIN := $(MYVAR)
```

I'd like this to print

```
hello
world
```

instead of

```
world
world
```

In other words, in the recipe `@echo $(MYVAR)`, I'd like `$(MYVAR)` to resolve when it is parsed.  Or perhaps someone knows another way of passing the value of a variable that may change later to the recipe.

**EDIT:**

The fix to make this work, as solved by MadScientist, is to change depchain.mk as follows.

**depchain.mk**

```
$(MYVAR) : MYVAR := $(MYVAR)

$(MYVAR) : $(DEPCHAIN)
    @echo $(MYVAR)

DEPCHAIN:= $(MYVAR)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm assuming that your example is not really a good representation of your actual requirements, because if you really just want to get the name of the target you can use automatic variables (`$@`) for that:

```
$(MYVAR): $(DEPCHAIN)
        @echo $@
```

In general there are two ways to handle this.  The first is constructed variable names, like this:

```
hello_MYVAR = foo
world_MYVAR = bar

$(MYVAR): $(DEPCHAIN)
        @echo $($@_MYVAR)
```

The second is target-specific variables, like this:

```
hello: MYVAR = foo
world: MYVAR = bar

$(MYVAR): $(DEPCHAIN)
        @echo $(MYVAR)
```

If these are not sufficient you'll have to be more forthcoming about your real requirements and restrictions.

Comment: You, sir, are amazing. The second option is exactly what I was looking for.